# ggplot legend for variable color and linetype not showing - geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a simple line graph of these maximum and minimum temperatures of two different climate models, with different colors for treatment (AmbT vs. ElevT) and different line types for max vs. min.

```
  Temp.C. Day AmbT_Max ElevT_Max AmbT_Min ElevT_Min
1       0  0d    23.00     23.78    11.10     13.80
2       5 15d    23.00     23.78    11.10     13.80
3      10 30d    25.42     27.31    13.68     15.91
4      15 45d    27.68     29.57    15.90     18.13
5      20 60d    28.72     33.03    17.37     20.72
6      25 75d    28.59     32.91    17.78     21.12
```

So far, I've tried this code and produced a graph that looks the way I want, but for some reason I cannot get the legend to show up in the graph. Here is my code:

```
TempPlot <- ggplot(Temps, aes(y=Temp(C), x=Day, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=AmbT_Max, x=Day), color="dodgerblue2", show.legend=TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(y=ElevT_Max, x=Day), color="violetred2", show.legend=TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(y=AmbT_Min, x=Day), color="dodgerblue2", linetype="dashed", show.legend=TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(y=ElevT_Min, x=Day), color = "violetred2", linetype = "dashed", show.legend=TRUE) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name="", values = c("AmbT_Max"=rep("solid"), "ElevT_Max"=rep("solid"), "AmbT_Min"=rep("dashed"), "ElevT_Min"=rep("dashed"))) +
  scale_color_manual(name="", values = c("AmbT_Max"="dodgerblue2","ElevT_Max"="violetred2", "AmbT_Min"="dodgerblue2", "ElevT_Min"="violetred2"))
```

And the graph I was able to produce:

[image]

I'm pretty new to ggplot, so maybe I'm doing something wrong with the scale_linetype_manual and scale_color_manual?

I also tried rearranging my data to look like this, since I know this is probably the better way to do it:

```
Temp.C. Day Treatment Type
1   23.00  0d      AmbT  Max
2   23.00 15d      AmbT  Max
3   25.42 30d      AmbT  Max
4   27.68 45d      AmbT  Max
5   28.72 60d      AmbT  Max
6   28.59 75d      AmbT  Max
...
31   18.13  45d     ElevT  Min
32   20.72  60d     ElevT  Min
33   21.12  75d     ElevT  Min
34   20.19  90d     ElevT  Min
35   19.67 105d     ElevT  Min
36   17.01 120d     ElevT  Min
```

and tried this code with ggplot:

```
TempPlot <- ggplot(TempsAlt, aes(y="Temp(C)", x=Day, color=Treatment, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y="Temp(C)"), linetype=TempsAlt$Type, show.legend=TRUE) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(rep("solid"), rep("dashed"))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("dodgerblue2", "violetred2"))
```

I've looked through many other questions on here that make their plots this way, but every variation of this code gives me an error: "`geom_line()` can't have varying colour, linewidth, and/or alpha along the line when linetype isn't solid"

This confuses me because I've seen other people use geom_line this way where it works, but maybe there was an update to ggplot2 that made this not possible? I'm not sure, but any help on getting the legend to show up is much appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you change `Day` to be an integer or a factor, otherwise if/when you jump to 100+ days, your axis will fall out of order.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way how we could do it:
What we are doing:
thanks to @r2evans (one pivot_longer instead of calling twice, and replacing `size` in `geom_line` (deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0) with `linewidth`:

First we bring the data in long format. The trick to get the line in correct form is to use `group = interaction(Treatment, Type)`:

```
library(tidyverse)

Temps %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Day, names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)", 
               names_to = c("Treatment", "Type"), 
               values_to = "Temp(C)") %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Day, y = `Temp(C)`, color = Treatment, linetype = Type)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = interaction(Treatment, Type)), linewidth = 1.2)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed")) +
  labs(x = "Day", y = "Temperature (°C)", color = "Climate Model", linetype = "Temperature Type") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Single pivot: `pivot_longer(Temps, -Day, names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)", names_to = c("Treatment", "Type"), values_to = "Temp(C)")`

Comment: (Actually, that's not quite right ... the `Temp.C.` column is messing that up)

Comment: I think you can go with the single-pivot after removing `Temp.C.` since it's never plotted.

Comment: FYI, `Warning: Using \`size\` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0. Please use \`linewidth\` instead.`

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew changing the data to long format was probably the way to go, but I couldn't figure out how to get past the "geom_line() can't have varying colour, linewidth, and/or alpha along the line when linetype isn't solid" error I was getting. This worked!